# 2005 VW Golf battery/PCM

Tags: starting

I was replacing the PCM in my golf, and ‘someone’ forgot to disconnect the battery. So after I pulled out the pcm and put the other one in. My car will not start. Are there any solutions to get it back up and driving

Answer (score 2):

Removing the pcm with out disconnecting battery is not really a big deal. Your car will not start because your immobilizer is active from switching the PCM.
You will need to have the immobilizer data cloned over, the replacement PCM programmed properly or have the immobilizer tuned out of it.